# Counting the number of characters from a file without using fopen()

Tags: c, file, input

I would like to count the characters from files using C.
I am curious if I open file using `open()` instead of `fopen()`, is there any functions I can use to count any characters? `open()` takes arguments, the first of which is a char array.

Assume if `fopen()` is not used then `fscanf()` is not used.

I am new to C. Just curious how it can work.

Comment: Pretty much everywhere, you can get the file size in bytes without opening it at all. BUT: That's bytes, not characters. Do you really want characters? Which encoding?

Comment: The `open` function is usually lower-level than `fopen` and friends, and on POSIX systems (like e.g. Linux and Mac OSX) is a native system call (and so used by the higher-level `fopen`). I recommend you read [an `open` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) to learn more about it, as well as check the related function (see the bottom of the linked page). There should also be many examples and tutorials all over the wider Internet if you just search a little.

Comment: @deviantfan I think I need to get bytes. I thought they were the same...Any difference?

Comment: "count the characters" - elaborate

Comment: @JiajuShen Think about the common [UTF-8 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), where only the low 127 characters of the [ASCII character set](http://www.asciitable.com/) fits in a single byte. Or if the file using a fixed-width multi-byte encoding like [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32). Then a single character can (or will) be multiple bytes.

Comment: If you only need the number of bytes in the file, just `stat()` it.

Comment: @JiajuShen Very simpified: You probably know of the ASCII code which maps numbers (usually 1 byte) to symbols like 65=A and 97=a. The problem is, there are many other systems than the ASCII, some of them use more than 1 byte per char (the upside is better support for other languages than English). Your file may have text which such a multibyte encoding (pure ASCII is a rarity nowadays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working on a POSIX.1-2001 compatible system you can use `stat` or `fstat` which return a `struct stat` which has a field `st_size` for the size in bytes. In POSIX 1 char = 1 byte = 8 bits.

If your system doesn't conform to POSIX.1 you can use `open` and repeated `read`s to find the size.